Enable a specific cipher suite for Java 11
We've been having trouble starting a Java application due to handshake failures. Upon inspection, we've discovered that the application can't connect to the server because the server expects a specific cipher suite (TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256), but the client doesn't have it in its hello message.
I would like to know if there's a way to enable the cipher suite for the client to use it in its hello. I'm not much of an expert in SSL/TLS, what would I need to understand to tackle this?

Java Version: 11.0.22
JRE Vendor: Red Hat, Inc.
JVM Version: 11.0.22+7-LTS

java -version:
openjdk version "11.0.22" 2024-01-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-11.0.22.0.7-1) (build 11.0.22+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-11.0.22.0.7-1) (build 11.0.22+7-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

java.security jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms entry:
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
    DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
    include jdk.disabled.namedCurves

java.security jdk.disabled.namedCurves entry:
jdk.disabled.namedCurves = secp112r1, secp112r2, secp128r1, secp128r2, \
    secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, secp192k1, secp192r1, secp224k1, \
    secp224r1, secp256k1, sect113r1, sect113r2, sect131r1, sect131r2, \
    sect163k1, sect163r1, sect163r2, sect193r1, sect193r2, sect233k1, \
    sect233r1, sect239k1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, \
    sect571k1, sect571r1, X9.62 c2tnb191v1, X9.62 c2tnb191v2, \
    X9.62 c2tnb191v3, X9.62 c2tnb239v1, X9.62 c2tnb239v2, X9.62 c2tnb239v3, \
    X9.62 c2tnb359v1, X9.62 c2tnb431r1, X9.62 prime192v2, X9.62 prime192v3, \
    X9.62 prime239v1, X9.62 prime239v2, X9.62 prime239v3, brainpoolP256r1, \
    brainpoolP320r1, brainpoolP384r1, brainpoolP512r1

java.security crypto.policy entry:
crypto.policy=unlimited

I've made a standalone Java class that prints all the supported ciphers and protocols (client-side):
try {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault();
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

    System.out.println("Supported Ciphers:");
    for (String cipher: sslSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites()) {
        System.out.println(cipher);
    }

    System.out.println("\nSupported Protocols:");
    for (String protocol: sslContext.getSupportedSSLParameters().getProtocols()) {
        System.out.println(protocol);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

This is the output:
Supported cipher suites:
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA

Supported protocols:
TLSv1.3
TLSv1.2
TLSv1.1
TLSv1
SSLv3
SSLv2Hello

As you can see, there's no mention of "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256". How could I enable that specific cipher suite? A few days ago, I don't know how, but the cipher suite appeared on the list, I really don't know what we did, so, I know its possible. Now it doesn't appear because we changed the Java installation (but anyways, both were Java 11).

Out of interest I just ran that with Open JDK 8 and it has it. A licensing issue maybe(?)

(@g00se) so does (my) Oracle 11.0.22+9-LTS-219 -- and versions both older and newer up to 22(.0.0). Mauricio: to be clear, you are running the test class directly (i.e. as 'main') in your JVM, not embedded within any larger app, framework or platform? What is the entry in your $JAVA/conf/security/java.security for jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms (please edit into Q, not as a comment) and is there any indication it (or the file) has been changed after installation?

Also note SSLv3 and TLSv1 should absolutely not be used today, and TLSv1.1 shouldn't if avoidable, and Oracle packages have these disabled, but yours apparently doesn't. Recent RedHat systems (since 8 IIRC) have a systemwide crypto policy that overrides some individual program settings -- do you have such a system, and if so what is it set to?

Thanks for the comments. @dave_thompson_085 The test class is standalone, also, I've edited the question to include a few lines from the java.security file, which, I've edited before, but currently I have it as it came stock. And yes, my system is a Red Hat Enterpirse Linux 8.6 (Ootpa).

Hmm, that's weird, you've specified that TLSv1.1 is disabled, while you get support for TLSv1.1 in supported protocols? Something is not right with the configuration.

@MaartenBodewes+ ignore what I said about versions; I rechecked and "supported protocols" does NOT reflect the disable settings (unlike "supported ciphersuites"). Your configured disable settings are the same as mine, but you're still getting a different result, including 'null' suites that should be disabled according to your config; it would be nice to call (in the failing=RedHat JVM) java.security.Security.getProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms") and see if that is different somehow, although I see you've found a bypass and may not want to bother.

So, I solved the issue, and yes, it had to do with the Java Distribution I was using.
I was using Red Hat Inc.'s Java Distribution, installed via Red Hat's repositories with yum, but, apparently, RH's Java doesn't support the cipher suite I was looking for. @g00se's comment kinda helped me there when they mentioned 'licensing'. So, based on the comments I got on my question, I went and downloaded an .rpm for Java, but this time Oracle's.
With that, I installed it on my RHEL server:
rpm -ivh jdk-11.0.21_linux-x64_bin.rpm

And then ran my class to check if any new cipher suites were added, and sure enough, there it was, 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256'.
From there, I just specified in my service file (the one that runs the application that was having the handshake failure) to use the Oracle's Java, like this:
ExecStart=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11-oracle-x64/bin/java ...other options... -jar "application.war"

And everything worked fine, no more errors!
Thanks for all your comments, they really helped me out :)

No problem. "Licensing" was a little woolly from me. What I was really getting at is THIS
